# Vote to accept a question if it is worthy rather than to close when it is unworthy

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

It is my impression that most new questions on SESE are closed quickly, often rightfully so. This is problematic for a number of reasons. We have been urged to be friendly and welcoming. Having your first question closed probably doesn't make anyone feel welcome, regardless the reason for closure. And someone may be writing an extensive answer only to find they cannot post it because the question was closed while they were writing.

So how about a scheme like Jira's: You can propose a question which will then require votes to be opened.

This will lower expectations and increase the threshold for people to write a question in the first place (it is no longer free, you will be encouraged to figure out what it takes for a question to be accepted upfront).

A proposal can be rejected on the same grounds questions are currently being closed on. If it gets 3 open votes before it gets 3 rejection votes it enters the Open state and only then people can answers the question.

If it does not get enough votes within a month to be either rejected or opened it can be deleted automatically (apparently no one cares about it or deems it interesting enough). After rejection it may be kept on for a while to allow editing and a greater number of votes to open it after all before deleting it.

It seems to me this would keep the noise down. You could then go to new open questions and find good quality questions to be answered. Or you can go to proposals and cast your opinion on them. But they would be separate sections on the site. The second one may even be invisible to members with insufficient reputation.

Comment: How does your proposal compare to the "Staging Ground" being proposed here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377768/how-might-the-staging-ground-the-new-ask-wizard-work-on-the-stack-exchange-net ?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I was unaware of this effort that seems to address the same problem. Before I posted I did a couple of searches on keywords used in the topic of my question and nothing came up so I figured my idea had to be totally original. The main difference seems to be that my rules a more rigid, simple and clear. And I would want to route all questions through this process, not just those of new users with low reputation.